# ASSERT failure after deleting my qt class on seprate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, assert, delete-operator

If I have a class `FunctionsClass` that inherits `QObject` and has a `QTcpServer` and `QTcpClient` in it as member variables. In my main UI class I set up the `FunctionsClass` member variable on a `Qthread` called `FunctionClassThread` by doing:

```
FunctionsClass *classObj = new FunctionsClass // (classObj is a class member)
classObj->moveToThread( &FunctionClassThread );
FunctionClassThread.start();

// connected some signal/slots..
// do some stuff...
```

Then I deconstruct the object containing my instance of `FunctionsClass` by doing:

```
FunctionClassThread.quit();
FunctionClassThread.wait();
delete classObj; // problem line...........
```

This error only happens when `classObj's` `QTcpServer` is currently listening or its`QTcpSocket` is attempting to connect to a server and I delete `classObj`. The error is: ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread.
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After moving `classObj` to another thread, you can no longer delete it from the thread you created it in. You either have to delete it within your `FunctionsClassThread` or move it back to the main thread via code **which is processed within the `FunctionsClassThread`.**

Read the Qt docs on [moveToThread()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#moveToThread):

> This function can only "push" an object from the current thread to
>   another thread, it cannot "pull" an object from any arbitrary thread
>   to the current thread.

So just before your FunctionsClassThread is about to stop, it has to call

```
classObj->moveToThread( QApplication::thread() );
```

Of course your FunctionsClassThread needs to be aware of the object, either directly, or by using signals & slots

Answer (score 0):

A **QObject** has thread affinity. It only likes to be manipulated from the thread it was created in . Use  [**QMetaObject::invokeMethod**](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/thread-basics.html) to invoke a method in context of another thread

Comment: I don't pass a parent to the FunctionsClass so how could it know that it was created in the main UI thread?